# ios HTTP basic authentication with wrong user/password (401 unauthorized extra data)

Tags: ios, http, basic-authentication, wireshark

I have one small problem with HTTP basic authentication.
I have some web sevice (REST) which provides some JSON for me.
I have neither service sources nor access to this server.

I can authenticate on server using correct user name and password.
Here is the code I'm using:

```
NSString *path = @"http://user:pwd@%bla.bla.com/api_key/";
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:urlRequest
        success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
            NSLog(@"Response: %@", JSON);
            if (successBlock) {
                successBlock(...);
            }
        } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
            if (errorBlock) {
                errorBlock(error, JSON);
            }
        }];

[operation setAuthenticationChallengeBlock:^(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *challenge) {
    if (challenge.previousFailureCount == 0) {
        NSURLCredential *credentials = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:username password:password
                                                               persistence:(NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone)];
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:credentials forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
    else {
        //[[challenge sender] continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        NSLog(@"Login error: Are credentials correct?");
        if (errorBlock) {
            //errorBlock(challenge.error, challenge.failureResponse);
        }
    }

    NSURLRequest* req = connection.currentRequest;
    AFJSONRequestOperation* op = operation;
    NSLog(@"hdr %@",challenge.error);
}];

[operation setRedirectResponseBlock:^NSURLRequest *(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLRequest *request, NSURLResponse *redirectResponse) {
    NSLog(@"redirect");
    return request;
}];

[operation start];
```

The problem is that I have no idea how to get an extra data sent by server on authentication failure (It sends extra strings which shows what was wrong, username or password).
I logged all http authentication process with wrong password by using Wireshark app.

Here is the screenshot with one authentication attempt (with wrong password):
[image]

I see that server really sends a plaintext notification that password is incorrect, but I have no idea how and where to catch it.

Any ideas?

Thx in advance.